# Where is "this" pointing at?

Tags: java, this

I know the piece of code below is far from perfect but it does what I want it to do. My problem is that I can't understand what object is the "this" keyword pointing at.

```
public class Browser extends JFileChooser{

  public File browser_creation(){

    int r;

    JFileChooser browser1 = new JFileChooser();        
    r = browser1.showOpenDialog(this);


    if (r == Browser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return browser1.getSelectedFile();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: "Far from perfect". It is not that bad. ;) Only the `extends JFileChooser` isn't good. Replace the `this` with `null` and it is getting better.

Comment: this and using browser1 instead of Browser inside the if statement. Well, for such a small piece of code these are quite a lot of things :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` points to the current instance of Browser. In other words, it is referring to the object that it is being executed in.

Here is some more information from the Java tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 5):

It points to `Browser` object the `browser_creation()` instance method is executed on.

Answer (score 2):

`browser_creation()` is an instance method, meaning that it is specific to the object it is called on.  The `this` keyword refers to the current object.  For example, calling `myObject.browser_creation()` would make `this` refer to myObject.